# What does “hangs a cloud of thoughts…” mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, metaphors, literature, rhetoric

I want to know what this sentence means; particularly the part that says "hangs a cloud of thoughts":

> About what goes on today **hangs a cloud of thoughts** concerning similar
>   things undergone in bygone days.
>   [*The Middle Works of John Dewey*](https://books.google.it/books?id=T6TJs5T0rfoC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22what%20goes%20on%20today%20hangs%20a%20cloud%20of%20thoughts%22&source=bl&ots=kEvmAyRn9i&hl=en&sa=X)

It is difficult for me to understand this sentence. It was used on an exam.

Answer (score 1):

"About", used here, is a slightly old fashioned usage meaning 'around'. If something hangs about something, it hangs around it. If you have long hair, it hangs about your head. You can re-write the sentence slightly:

> A cloud of thoughts hangs about what goes on today concerning similar
>   things undergone in bygone days.

The writer means that when someone considers what goes on today, there are a number of thoughts of what happened in bygone days.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the first paragraph where the line appears, its meaning becomes more apparent

> Man differs from the lower animals because he preserves his past experiences. About **what goes on today hangs a cloud of thoughts** concerning similar things undergone in bygone days. With the animals, an experience perishes as it happens, and each new doing or suffering stands alone. But man lives in a world where each occurrence is charged with echoes and reminiscences of what has gone before, where each event is a reminder of other things.

There is a common English idiom, which @Jagatha Narasimharao hinted at in their answer, that helps explains the symbolism that lies behind *“hangs a cloud of thoughts”*

> **[a cloud hanging over somebody](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-cloud-hanging-over-sb)**
>   a situation or future event that makes you worry or feel unhappy:
>
> *When you're waiting for an operation, you feel like there's a cloud hanging over 
>   you.*

Thus the author is suggesting that the experiences of man–intending humanity–that afflict and occur during his lifetime do not disappear on his deathbed, but continue to exist and “dangle” over his successors as if stored in a cloud. As a dark cloud may warn people that rain is expected to, so too the metaphorical cloud that is suspended above over head  continually reminds us of the trials and tribulations our forefathers experienced (*[undergone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undergo)*) in their lifetime (*[bygone days](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bygone)*). Whatever we do today is influenced by the past and its knowledge (thoughts) as if stored in a cloud, the harbinger of what lies ahead.

Answer (score -1):

What happens today causes to think of many similar things that happened in the past.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange.   Your answer is very short and does not contain enough details to help a learner understand the example.   I also find at least one grammar problem ("causes to think").  To improve your answer, can you please explain how the learner should understand the example sentence, which is relatively complicated.   **Please read** the ["Guide to Contributors"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners?cb=1) and then keep contributing!

Answer (score -1):

The sentence means: What is going on today reminds me of a number of thoughts about similar things that happened in the past.

**A cloud hangs over** is an idiom which means someone or something is surrounded by general feeling of distrust resulting from a particular event in the recent past.

*Hangs a cloud of thoughts* connotes that the speaker was surrounded by many distressing moments in the past which came to his mind when he faces a similar situation now.

I think **a cloud hangs over** is similar to **hangs a cloud of thoughts**.

Lastly, **bygone days** means **the days in the past**.

Comment: It doesn't say 'a cloud hangs over'. It says 'a cloud hangs **about**'.